# jQuery - select a range of classes except one

Tags: jquery

I have a range of classes that i need to target and would appreciate a little guidance

There must be a better way of coding this rather than putting in all the classes and commas...

```
$(".btn01").click(function() {
$('#box01').fadeIn();
$('#box02,#box03,#box04,#box05,#box06,#box07,#box08,#box09').hide();
});

$(".btn02").click(function() {
$('#box02').fadeIn();
$('#box01,#box03,#box04,#box05,#box06,#box07,#box08,#box09').hide();
});

$(".btn03").click(function() {
$('#box03').fadeIn();
$('#box01,#box02,#box04,#box05,#box06,#box07,#box08,#box09').hide();
});
```

Thanks id advance
Al

Comment: looks like a lot of ids and not classes !?

Comment: only btn01, btn02 and btn03 are classes, if your boxes all have the same class you can easily hide them with $("."+CLASS_NAME).hide();

Comment: can you share some of your markup or create a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net please, and let us know if we could add another class to some elements or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think , this can be a simpler approach to do what you want

> Jquery Selector **[id^=box]** selects all elements with an **id** attribute value starting with **"box"**

**Code:**

```
$(".btn01").click(function() { 
$("[id^='box']").hide();
$('#box1').show();    
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hsakapandit/3r7WA/

Answer (score 1):

You can use starts with selector `^`

```
$('[id^=box]');
```

Combining everything would give:

```
$('[class^=btn]').click(function(e){
   $('[id^=box]').hide(); // hide everything
   $('#box'+e.target.className.match(/\d+$/)[0]).fadeIn();  // show only this
});
```

As noted in the comments, you would be better off by using classes instead of ids.

Comment: while he could do that, it's not really what he should be doing, he would be better off giving them all a unique class and utilizing that to hide them, using jquery to search for part of strings in the DOM can lead to unexpected behavior, especially if he has anything else with 'box' in the id name.

Answer (score 1):

You could exclude a specific id with "not":

```
$(".btn03").click(function() {
  $('#box03').fadeIn();
  $('[id^=box]').not('#box03').hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nanego - that's exactly what i was after!

Comment: ugh, I'm rather disappointed that you would use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

**LETS DO THIS, *GENERIC STYLE***

[**__-----> JSFIDDLE LINK <-----__**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgleeson/HAR9V/)
say you have your html, and your button could look like this.

```
<input type='button' value='Click Me!' class='btnClass'/>
```

Then for each button that has a special box it should be showing, you add some custom data attributes.

```
<input type='button' value='Click Me!' class='btnClass' c-data-attr-boxid='box1'/>
```

and your boxes need some classes too.

```
<div id='box1' class='boxes'></div>
```

Then in your Javascript/Jquery you do something like this.

```
$(".btnClass").click(function(){
     var id = this.attr('c-data-attr-boxid');
     $(".boxes").hide();
     $("#"+id).show();
});
```